# save new tab data in separate table when save cms >> page form

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am developing a module in magento. I added a new Tab in CMS >> Page core module through my custom module. I want to save new tab data in separate table which one created by custom module. My problem is that I don't know how can I save new tab data in my new table when  core page's save/edit functionality works?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer this problem now. Here is [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6745/save-new-tab-data-in-separate-table-when-save-cms-page-data)

actually I post this question in two panel of the StackExchange (stackoverflow & magento.stackexchange). I got answer on magento.stackexchange. Thanks to ProxiBlue, who resolve my issue.

Here I am sharing this thread for whom are mostly stackoverflow  visitors.